# Can recovered R410-A refrigerant be reused upon compressor replacement?

Tags: hvac

My HVAC technician came to see my shorted compressor for replacement. He indicated that he may be able to reuse the same refrigerant if he finds that it hasn't been too contaminated once he recovers it and the pipes look clean (if the compressor oil didn't mix with it).

I called another place and they said definitely replace the refrigerant no matter what. Now, they have a reason to lie because they mark the refrigerant price ridiculously (from something like $9/lb, if they get a 30 lb tank available on ebay in the $200 range, to something like $120/lb).

Is it reasonable to reuse the refrigerant if it is clean? I read that shorted compressors usually leak the oil and mix it with the refrigerant but this guy think it may be salvaged?

Also, I think I can order a 30lb tank of 410A on ebay for $230. I feel him charging me 120 is a ridiculous markup, is it customary to ask that I use my own refrigerant? And are different refrigerants of different quality?

Comment: Suppose the tech supplies the refrigerant and it's no good.  You get to make a warranty claim against the tech.  The tech gets to make a warranty claim against the supplier for parts and labor. That system works. *You want to step into the supplier's shoes. OK. Warranty work is on you, then.*

Comment: It can be re-used but most HVAC technicians won't reuse it.  Why?  Because there is no way to know if it's contaminated or not.  The only exception might be if you remove the refrigerant from a unit, do some repair, and then replace it into that same unit.  As far as the price the tech is charging you for new R410, that's a business deal between you and him/her.  If you don't like their price, find another tech!

Comment: Also, I think you are imagining that maintainers simply go "Psssssssssss" with the old refrigerant i.e. vent into atmosphere.  That is [not the case at all](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=14efdd59b914bdabd4c17d8c6597566c&mc=true&node=se40.21.82_1154&rgn=div8) (40 CFR 82.151 *et.seq.* notably 82.154.)  and has not been since 1992.  As such, *part and parcel* of swapping your refrigerant is vampiring out your old refrigerant and disposing of it properly.   This is probably the lion's share of the cost, and even if they use your refrigerant you still have to pay for that.

Answer (score 1):

What is your end-goal exactly, get new refrigerant for next to nil?

> He indicated that he may be able to reuse the same refrigerant if he finds that it hasn't been too contaminated once he recovers it and the pipes look clean (if the compressor oil didn't mix with it).

Sounds like this person is trying to be nice and looking to save you a few bucks.

> I called another place and they said definitely replace the refrigerant no matter what.

Sounds like this place isn't willing to deal with used refrigerant and I don't blame them.

Look into the difference between [recovering, recycling, and reclaiming refrigerant](http://www.refrigerantservicesllc.com/how-refrigerants-are-recycled/).

If I was running a car shop I would hysterically laugh at the person that asks me to use the old oil after an engine re-build. I don't care if they assure me that no anti-freeze mixed into the oil. If the customer insisted on such nonsense then I would tell them they have no warranty.

> I feel him charging me 120 is a ridiculous markup.

Well I feel like having a system's premature failure get blamed on used refrigerant to avoid honoring a warranty is going to be more ridiculous.

---

Do you not trust the first tech or something? Ask him for a quote for new refrigerant. Regardless, make sure to get a new high quality line filter installed.

Comment: To continue with the auto-repair shop analogy, ask to bring your own parts in and have them install them. Unless you've got a _good_ relationship with the shop, they'll hurt themselves laughing at you. (TBF, I did bring a partially completed drum-brake rebuild to my local shop with the parts I was attempting to install. They did install my parts for me, but I've been bringing work to them for 20+ years. i.e. I have a _good_ relationship with them.)

Comment: I don't want to be taken for a proverbial ride paying a >1000% markup

Comment: @amphibient It's your right to get multiple quotes. It's quite possible this is their "I don't want to do (have time for) this f###ing job so I'll quote high" price; there is **A LOT** of this going on given the current housing market. There is nothing stopping you from asking why their refrigerant price is marked up so high. How many pounds of refrigerant does your system need anyways? Ask the nice first guy if he'd be willing to use your eBay refrigerant, just don't expect him to warrant anything. Maybe let them keep the excess as a thank you.

Comment: `Well I feel like having a system pre-maturely fail, potentially because of used refrigerant, is going to be more ridiculous.` <-- I think this is a false dichotomy

Comment: @amphibient Well it doesn't matter if it's true or not. If the tech feels like blaming the refrigerant for every service call moving forward to avoid honoring a warranty then good luck proving them otherwise.

Comment: @amphibient I just looked up refrigerant specs and it takes 2-4 pounds per ton of cooling. So a 3-ton A/C will set you back $720-$1440 in refrigerant alone?!?! I now understand the outrage. However, the rule of thumb is that a company will try to charge whatever people are willing to pay. If you are not willing to negotiate then get more quotes. If there's a local $120/lb of refrigerant racket going on between all HVAC companies in your area then that's a separate issue

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I ordered 11 lb on ebay for $230

Comment: @amphibient Nice, so who will be charging your system with it?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, a guy I negotiated with to use my freon. He already did. Stop pushing the anti DIY and self reliance propaganda on a site dedicated to DIY

Comment: @amphibient Sorry if my question was misleading, I am most certainly not anti-diy. I was just wondering which person agreed to letting you buy your own refrigerant? My assumption is that you went with the nice guy who mentioned the possibility of re-using the old stuff, right? What was his quote if he supplies new refrigerant? I'm just trying to get an idea of normal markup versus the outrageous markup.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, a person with whom I negotiated such a deal